# Why do some siddurim switch the order of the angels?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer, malach-angel

I've noticed that in some siddurim in the prayer "El Adon" the last line has the order of the angels switched; that is, they say:

"seraphim, chayot, v'ophanei hakodesh"

instead of

"seraphim, ophanim, v'chayot hakodesh",

and yet all siddurim by Shema say "ophanim v'chayot hakodesh". So my question is what is the origin of this phrase (both by Birchot Kriat Shema and "El Adon") and why do some siddurim (e.g., Chabad) have the order of the melachim "flipped"?

Thanks

Comment: A reason for the first option is mentioned in [*Sha'ar HaKavanot*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%94), based off the *Tikunei Zohar*. It is mentioned already in the Rishonim (e.g. Abudraham, who says your second option should be used).
See also [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21834_120.pdf).

Comment: @Cauthon It looks like you may have an answer

Comment: @Cauthon Thank you so much! What is the last source you linked?

Comment: No problem :). The last source is from the 6th volume of a book called "סידור הגאונים והמקובלים והחסידים", written by [R' Moshe Yair Weinstock](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A7). Here's the [same page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21834&st=&pgnum=120&hilite=), with the rest of the book available.